# What can I do to avoid brush strokes in my Mod Podge?

Tags: decoupage-glue

If I am using Mod Podge as a finish on something small, like 2x4 letter blocks, I apply the adhesive with a paint brush. When it dries, I can clearly see the brush strokes.

Is it the brush I am using?

Is this just something that happens when using Mod Podge?

Answer (score 7):

When applying the Mod Podge, use a soft, wide brush and as few brush strokes as possible, as it begins to set quickly. If you can brush it on with only one or two strokes, that is best. Use very thin coats.

Ideally, use a different medium. I think part of the problem is just the Mod Podge itself. I no longer use it because I think it has a haze when it dries. I like to use Delta Ceramcoat Varnish or Annie Howes Glamour Seal. The Glamour Seal can also be used as an adhesive.

Answer (score 6):

Mod Podge does love to be streaky, but there are ways to lessen the extent of streakiness.

I prefer to use a wide foam brush when applying Mod Podge. Also, there are spray varieties of Mod Podge - the same ol' Mod Podge you know and love, but in an aerosol can like spray paint.

You can also try applying multiple layers, with brush strokes in different directions between layers to try to fill in the gaps.

Lastly, if you *really* don't want streaks, you can sand between Mod Podge coats.